# SRAM PG-1130 cassette manual? Meaning of numbers on spacers that go between sprockets?

Tags: gears, cassette

Took apart the individual sprockets on my SRAM PG-1130 cassette and the spacers (the ones between the cogs) were so dirty I didn't even see the numbers on them but each spacer has an 11 on it (makes sense, 11 speed) as well as another number on it. You'd assume the other number would be a number 1-6 (there are 6 spacers) but they are 2,3,3,5,6,8.

Not trying to overthinking it but I missed some letters on the rear derailleur pulleys when I cleaned them a couple months ago that indicate which way they should face and it caused a lot of noise/shifting problems. I finally came across a YouTube video of a guy breaking it down, SRAM has no user manual for the Apex 1 derailleur.

SRAM's online user manuals seems ridiculously bad, I never got any with my bike (bought it from a shop who assembled the bike, so that's on them) but feel like you should be able to look up the part number and get the user manual for it but all I could find is [this](https://www.servicearchive.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/95-2518-002-000_rev_f_user_manual_cassettes_and_chains_0.pdf) which is super high level and doesn't even cover this specific cassette. Pretty ridiculous.

Also does anyone know if I should grease the spacers when I assemble the cassette? or just on the hub?

Comment: Do some cogs come assembled in groups? Especially the larger ones? Are all spacers identical in shape and thickness, I guess they are? The numbers may indicate the relative position in the cassette. With #2 sitting between cog 1 & 2, I'd rather say between 2 & 3 because often cog 1 has some kind of 'collar' and isn't flat.

Comment: cog 1,2,3 are assembled in a group. And i agree on relative position but then why are there some that have the same number. And they appear relatively the same

Comment: On the assembled cassette the cogs should be evenly spaced. Try this: the bloc of three, ring, cog, ring and so on. If you have a vernier calliper, check the rings for equal thickness. Otherwise place ring 8 on the bloc and count down. The 4th largest cog is possibly different.from the others?? The numbers on the spacers may be irrelevant imho.

Comment: Do the spacers look identical? Often plastic parts have a number molded into them which corresponds to the set of moulds they came from, so that problems can be traced back.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: even if the spacers are metal, the reason could be the same, to identify a faulty die.

Comment: When I remove a cassette made of separate bits I slide it from the hub onto an adequately sized metal tube* to preserve the order of elements. The metal tube resists to solvents and pressure cleaner. (*cut from a discarded metal broom handle)

Comment: @Carel I’ve seen old bulk blank CD cases use for the same purpose

Comment: As a first measure I should find out if the spacers are different. Measure width with a vernier caliper. If you don't have one, order one, for later. Yet, compare the width of the spacers by putting them next to each other on a flat surface.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but does it align to the number of teeth difference from cog to cog?

That could be approximately correct except for the 36-42.

No, you don't grease the spacers, they are plastic so the will not corrode and seize to any other part.

The spacers will all be the same thickness for any number of cogs (6/7/8/9/10/11/12) as it aligns to the amount the derailleur moves per click.

Using any spacer that varies at all for that number of cogs will result in really poor shifting